# Calling moveToThread() doesn't move QObject to another thread.

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

Let `functionClass` be a class derived from `QObject`. In the class constructor of my `QMainWindow` class (which hasn't started any other threads) I have the following code:

```
QThread workThread;
functionClass *functionClassObj = new functionClass;

cout << functionClassObj->thread()->currentThreadId() << endl; // prints 0x16c
functionClassObj->moveToThread( &workThread );
cout << functionClassObj->thread()->currentThreadId() << endl; // prints 0x16c
```

Why do the `currentThreadId()`functions print the same thing if I make a call to `moveToThread()`?

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but allocating the QThread object on the stack isn't a good idea, as it will be destroyed at the end of the QMainWindow constructor.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`currentThreadId()` is a static member of QThread.  This means that

```
functionClassObj->currentThreadId();
```

is equivalent to

```
QThread::currentThreadId();
```

which means that you're going to get the same return value regardless of any object you use or don't use to call the function.

The function in question returns the id of the *currently executing thread*, and not the thread affinity of the object that you're trying to call it on.

If you want to get a reference to the thread object that the object has affinity for, use `QObject::thread()` instead.